# AutoKeras 1.0 - cannot import load_image_dataset

Tags: keras, auto-keras

After switching to AutoKeras 1.0 cannot any longer to import load_image_dataset function.

Tried:

```
from autokeras.image.image_supervised import load_image_dataset

from autokeras import load_image_dataset
```

Nothing seems to work.

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem.  According to an issue on the github repo, 'load_image_dataset' is no longer included in autokeras:

https://github.com/keras-team/autokeras/issues/862

I'm probably going to manually implement this functionality.  I'll let you know how it goes.